# IBM Cloud Code Engine: IAM setup for "service instance"

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-code-engine, ibm-cloud-iam

I am in the process of setting up structures for a development process with IBM Cloud Code Engine. The documentation says "service instance" in the privilege matrix, but I wonder if Code Engine projects are meant. I want to only grant few developers the ability to create new projects.
[image: Code Engine platform privileges]

Would I grant **Platform Editor** to create a Code Engine project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Editor role would be the appropriate role to assign. In other Code Engine documentation, on [how to retrieve the ID of the Code Engine service instance](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/codeengine?topic=codeengine-api#api-guid), it is noted that:

> Identify the service instance that represents your Code Engine project and determine the GUID from the output.

Thus, the concept of IBM Cloud service instance maps to a Code Engine project.